# Preposition for involved and per cent

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct option, please?

1. He will be involved **at** 45 per cent of his workload.
2. He will be involved **with** 45 per cent of his workload.
3. He will be involved **in** 45 per cent of his workload.

Comment: What scenario is this meant to represent?

Comment: Are "he" and "his" two different people?

Comment: It is about what percentage of working time a person spend working on a project. He and his refer to the same person.

Comment: "He will be involved for 45% of his working hours." _Workload_ is an amount of work, not of time.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: So 'the workload of 100 hours' is nonsence?

Comment: None of the three options is very clear as it stands; it is only after you have provided your first comment above that one begins to understand what you are trying to say. Of the three prepositions you offer, *at* is probably the best, although *for* might work better; *in* definitely doesn't work for what you are trying to say. *Involved*, however, calls for an explication of what he will be involved **in**, such as 'He will be involved in this project for 45% of his workload'.

Comment: Thank you very much. And after participate, will be there the preposition with? He will participate with 45% on the project.

Comment: If it is about time, then "of his working hours" or just "45% of his time" (where working hours are assumed because workplaces don't control the rest of time). But workload isn't necessarily synonymous with time - it might refer e.g. to the number of cases/clients/projects.